# Why is Windows defaulting Num Lock to off?

Tags: windows, numlock

For many years now, every time I install Windows I have to go through hoops to get the Num Lock to stay on. Registry tweaks and/or lock screen reboots.

Does anyone have any idea why would Microsoft default it's state to off?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check similar setting as below
[image]